# C++ no suitable conversion function from INPUT to LPINPUT exists

Tags: c++, winapi

i'm trying to get the coordinates of the mouse, then move the mouse relative to those coordinates.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    SHORT f5;
    POINT pt{};
    MOUSEINPUT _mi{};
    INPUT mm{};
    mm.type = 0;
    for (;;) {
        f5 = GetAsyncKeyState(0x74);
        if (f5 > 0) {
            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            _mi.dx = pt.x + 100;
            _mi.dy = pt.y + 100;
            mm.mi = _mi;
            SendInput(1, mm, sizeof(mm));   
        }
        Sleep(50);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error saying that no suitable conversion from INPUT to LPINPUT exists, but I also have no idea how to create a "LPINPUT" struct.

Comment: "LPINPUT" means "Long Pointer to INPUT". You managed to make an `LPPOINT` from a `POINT`, so try using the same method.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the "detour" through `_mi`, you can `mm.mi.dx = pt.x + 100;` directly.

Comment: Just an FYI, you shouldn't use ["magic numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in your code, ie `mm.type = 0;` What does `0` represent? Someone else reading your code would have to take time to lookup the documentation to know its meaning, or infer its meaning from analyzing the context in which it is used. Better to write self-documenting code instead. The `SendInput()` API defines an `INPUT_MOUSE` constant for exactly this purpose, eg: `mm.type = INPUT_MOUSE;`

Answer (score 1):

`SendInput()` expects a pointer to an array of `INPUT` structures. Since you are passing only 1 `INPUT`, give it the address of your `INPUT` as a pointer by prefixing the structure with the `&` operator, just as you did with `GetCursorPos()`:

```cpp
SendInput(1, &mm, sizeof(mm));
```